# Grep and pGrep making up processes

Tags: python, bash, raspberry-pi3

I'm not familiar with bash at all, but I'm trying to make a pair of scripts that will detect

1. If a program is running.
2. If a python/bash script is running.

My code for nº1 is:

```
#!/bin/bash

X=$( pidof $1 )

if [ ${#X} -gt 0 ]
then
    echo "$1 has already $X been started"
else
    echo "$1 not started $X"
fi
```

Which works great, but won't detect scripts, so I made nº 2 with the change:

```
X=$( pgrep -f $1 )
```

At first nº2 it seemed to be working, but when I terminated the python script I still get:

```
WebsocketServer has 5 length and it's already 11919 started
```

If I do `ps -ax` the PID of the processes aren't nowhere to be seen.

But if I write `ps -ax | grep websocket`:

```
11921 pts/4    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto websocket
```

If I start the python script...

```
WebsocketServer has 11 length and it's already 11927 11935 started
```

What is happening? Am I somehow misusing the commands?

Edit: Forgot to mention that writing `pgrep -f WebsocketServer` in the terminal returns nothing, like it should.

Comment: Why are using `${#X}`, it gets the string length of  content stored in `X`, may be you wanted to `"$X"` to get the value stored.

Comment: What does `echo "$X"` show?

Comment: @Inian He just wants the length so he can tell if it contains anything or not.

Comment: @Barmar The PID of the process, each time I call the script the PID is incremented by 2 (I called the script 5 times, the values where 12867, 12869,12871...)

Comment: Does the script that's using `pgrep` contain `WebsocketServer` in its name?

Comment: The example output shows `websocket`, are you sure that `WebsocketServer` is also in the `ps` output (isn't it just `websocket`?). or use the ignore-case options, `...grep -i websocket ...` Good luck.

Comment: @Barmar No, the name is checkScriptAlive, but wait... maybe it's findind the argument?

Comment: Yes, it was. Damn it. It was finding the "check" script itself because the argument I pass has the same name as the process I want to find (logical, but dumb).

Comment: Yeah. `pgrep` is smart enough to ignore itself, but there's no way for it to know to ignore the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the argument to your script is the same as the script name you're searching for, and `pgrep -f` is finding the script.

Here's a trick you can try: split the name into two arguments.

```
checkScriptAlive websocket Server
```

Then in the script, do:

```
target="$1$2"
x=$(pgrep -f "$target")
```

Comment: I also found that using `pgrep -x` instead of -f solved the issue, but yeah, the source of the problem was the thing driving me crazy.